# Is there a shorter way to Try Catch ex As Exception in single line VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

For example when there is multiple exception I need to handle, below way takes more space.
Is there a shorter way to Try Catch ex As Exception in single line VB.NET? maybe something like `Try objSize = obj.Size Catch ex As Exception objSize = 0`

Also if anyone can share best practices for error handling in vb.net it'd be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
Try
    objSize = obj.Size
Catch ex As Exception
    objSize = 0
End Try
```

Comment: Why would you want to do it in one line? It makes the code harder to read and understand, doesn't save any keystrokes except a couple of enter keys, and won't make your code execute any faster. It also makes debugging much more difficult when you can't clearly see the flow of execution in the code, which you can in the code block you posted at the end.

Comment: I totally agree @KenWhite but if there are many handlers i need to place similar to this one the lines of code increases drastically. and m understand is different error handlers goes in different blocks of try and catch.

Comment: Lines of code are meaningless. Readability is much more important.

Comment: I agree. So there is no other way to write this in single line? Any other suggestions if there are many handlers to be in same sub?

Comment: Best practice is pretty subjective, but would I would suggest is not using exception handling for flow control and validation as per your example.  Would be much more efficient to check the value the value of obj.size is valid before exception handling even comes into it

Comment: Agree with @Hursey - potentially you are using Try/Catch to do more than it should.  Andex, maybe you should add more relevant code to explain why this is important to you.  Seems some context is missing.

Comment: Ok thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Yes, shorter way would be to wrap `Try .. Catch` into a method and call it everywhere where you need - you will get one line error handling

Answer (score 1):

There's a very good discourse in the comments on the question here and everyone raised valid points.

The only way that code will throw an exception is if retrieving the object size throws an exception. The only thing you do if it throws an exception is set the size to 0. Ergo, you should just make object.Size return 0 if it was going to throw an exception. No throwing needless exceptions is a best practice because they're expensive.

You can, however declare a sub that takes other subs as parameters:

```
Sub TryCatch(t as Action, c as Action)
    Try
        t()
    Catch 
        c()
    End try
End Sub
```

And then capture your lines of code  that you formerly trycatched, as subs:

```
Dim objSize = 0

TryCatch(Sub() objSize = obj.Size, Sub() objSize = 0)
```

Or you can use c# ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of one line **Try .. Catch**

```
Try : objSize = obj.Size : Catch ex As Exception : objSize = 0 : End Try
```

> **I'm just wondering how are you going to Debug your Code, if it only**
> **goes like that in bigger application ?!**

Answer (score 0):

The answer to how to do this is to not use a try catch block at all.

```
    objSize = If(obj?.Size, 0)
```

Does all you need it to in this case.

If you don’t like the syntax, then there’s this

```
    objSize =(obj?.Size).GetValueOrDefault
```

Either way, try catch blocks are for recovering from unknown errors, not ones that can be handled more easily with a simple change in how the code looks.